# Struggling with xPath sub selecting with conditionals

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I've been struggling with some xPath manipulation at the moment. I have this html **scraper** in Python that will parse the HTML tree after a specific set of `<li>` and extract its `text()`. The problem is that some of those `<li>` have an `<i class='ok'></i>` with no text inside.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
     <ul>
       <li>Text...</li>
       <li>Other text...</li>
       <li><i class='ok'></i></li>
       <li><i class='ok'></i>Another text...</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My xPath selector is as follow at the moment:

```
row_value = '(//div[contains(@id,"phone_columns")]' \
            '/div/ul[contains(@class,"phone_column_features")]' \
            '/li/text() | ' \
            '//div[contains(@id,"phone_columns")]' \
            '/div/ul[contains(@class,"phone_column_features")]' \
            '/li/i/@class)'
```

I want to get the class value in some occasions, but most of them the `text()` will do.

Current output:

```
[ "Text...", "Other text...", "ok", "ok", "Another text..." ]
```

Desired output:

```
[ "Text...", "Other text...", "ok", "ok Another text..." ]
```

Thanks in advance,
César Liedke

Comment: Can you... 1) Update your question with correct HTML sample as for now there are no nodes with `@class` or `@id` and second `li` node has no closing tag, 2) Share current output, 3) Share desired output?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally XPath like `//li/concat(i/@class, text())` should do the trick, but I'm quite sure that lxml doesn't support this syntax.

Instead you can use more complicated code:

```
source = lxml.html.fromstring(your_HTML)
li_nodes = source.xpath("//div/ul/li")  # replace this simplified XPath with actual XPath for li nodes

class_values = [i.xpath("./i/@class")[0] if i.xpath("./i/@class") else " " for i in li_nodes]
text_nodes = [i.text_content() if i.text_content() else " " for i in li_nodes]

output = [" ".join(item).strip() for item in zip(class_values, text_nodes)]
```

The output of `print(output)`:

```
['Text...', 'Other text...', 'ok', 'ok Another text...']
```

Comment: Perfect, @Andersson ! It is true that concat() is not supported by lxml, but the other code snippet worked just fine! Thanks for your time!